# Magento 2.2.9 - Removed class use still throws errors

Tags: system.log, magento2.2.9

In system.log, I keep receiving the error

> main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper does not exist.

I've removed/changed all references to this class, and when I grep the website the only result returned is the system.log file itself. What could be causing this?

I've blown caches, generated code, and static content to bits with no success.

Running Magento 2.2.9

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
rm -rf generated/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

 php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The classes need to get generated from `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Add the correct permissions to **generated** dir
Try **777** for test first.

This is for all site

```
./bin/cli find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
./bin/cli find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
./bin/cli chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: I've already tried this, which is why I'm so baffled!

Comment: updated my answer